Micronaut Serverless lambda not able to load partition metadata
I'm using Micronaut Java and building my image as graalvm and deploying that image on aws Lambda and internally code is interacting with dynamodb from lambda.
So, whenever code is reaching to dynamodb. I'm getting below error -
Message: Unable to load partition metadata from com/amazonaws/partitions/endpoints.json

Full stack trace -
09:13:28.771 [io-executor-thread-1] ERROR i.m.http.server.RouteExecutor - Unexpected error occurred: Error instantiating bean of type [com.example.userservice.service.Impl.UserServiceImpl]
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   Message: Unable to load partition metadata from com/amazonaws/partitions/endpoints.json
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   Path Taken: new $UserController$Definition$Intercepted(UserService userService,UserValidator userValidator,BeanResolutionContext $beanResolutionContext,BeanContext $beanContext,Qualifier $qualifier,List $interceptors) --> new $UserController$Definition$Intercepted([UserService userService],UserValidator userValidator,BeanResolutionContext $beanResolutionContext,BeanContext $beanContext,Qualifier $qualifier,List $interceptors) --> new UserServiceImpl([CognitoClient cognitoClient],UserRepository userRepository,PreferenceRepository preferenceRepository)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type [com.example.userservice.service.Impl.UserServiceImpl]
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   Message: Unable to load partition metadata from com/amazonaws/partitions/endpoints.json
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   Path Taken: new $UserController$Definition$Intercepted(UserService userService,UserValidator userValidator,BeanResolutionContext $beanResolutionContext,BeanContext $beanContext,Qualifier $qualifier,List $interceptors) --> new $UserController$Definition$Intercepted([UserService userService],UserValidator userValidator,BeanResolutionContext $beanResolutionContext,BeanContext $beanContext,Qualifier $qualifier,List $interceptors) --> new UserServiceImpl([CognitoClient cognitoClient],UserRepository userRepository,PreferenceRepository preferenceRepository)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2322)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2277)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2289)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3056)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:81)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2958)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2919)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2730)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1693)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanResolutionContext.getBean(AbstractBeanResolutionContext.java:89)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBean(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:2165)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1328)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at com.example.userservice.service.Impl.$UserServiceImpl$Definition.instantiate(Unknown Source)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2307)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2277)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2289)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3056)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:81)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2958)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2919)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2730)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1693)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanResolutionContext.getBean(AbstractBeanResolutionContext.java:89)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBean(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:2165)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1328)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at com.example.userservice.controller.$UserController$Definition$Intercepted$Definition.instantiate(Unknown Source)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2307)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2277)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2289)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3056)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:81)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2958)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2919)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2893)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1659)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext$BeanContextExecutionHandle.getTarget(DefaultBeanContext.java:4220)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext$BeanContextUnsafeExecutionHandle.invokeUnsafe(DefaultBeanContext.java:4187)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.web.router.AbstractRouteMatch.execute(AbstractRouteMatch.java:228)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestContext.with(ServerRequestContext.java:74)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.http.server.RouteExecutor.executeRouteAndConvertBody(RouteExecutor.java:480)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.http.server.RouteExecutor.lambda$callRoute$6(RouteExecutor.java:457)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.core.execution.ExecutionFlow.lambda$async$1(ExecutionFlow.java:87)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.core.propagation.PropagatedContext.lambda$wrap$3(PropagatedContext.java:211)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at java.base@17.0.11/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at java.base@17.0.11/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at java.base@17.0.11/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:885)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:860)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load partition metadata from com/amazonaws/partitions/endpoints.json
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at com.amazonaws.partitions.PartitionsLoader.build(PartitionsLoader.java:82)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at com.amazonaws.regions.RegionMetadataFactory.create(RegionMetadataFactory.java:30)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils.initialize(RegionUtils.java:64)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils.getRegionMetadata(RegionUtils.java:52)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils.getRegion(RegionUtils.java:106)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.getRegionObject(AwsClientBuilder.java:256)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.withRegion(AwsClientBuilder.java:245)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.withRegion(AwsClientBuilder.java:232)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at com.example.userservice.configuration.CognitoClient.createCognitoClient(CognitoClient.java:43)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at com.example.userservice.configuration.CognitoClient.<init>(CognitoClient.java:33)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at com.example.userservice.configuration.$CognitoClient$Definition.instantiate(Unknown Source)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2307)
2024-07-18T14:43:28.772+05:30   ... 47 common frames omitted

I've tried to add above mentioned endpoint in reflect.json, also tried to remove multiple jackson libraries. But those solution didn't worked as well.
Below is my build.gradle file
plugins {
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "8.1.1"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "4.0.3"
    id("io.micronaut.aot") version "4.0.3"
}

version = "0.1"
group = "com.example.userservice"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut.serde:micronaut-serde-processor")
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut.validation:micronaut-validation-processor")
    implementation("io.micronaut.aws:micronaut-aws-sdk-v2"){
        exclude group: "software.amazon.awssdk", module: "third-party-jackson-core"
    }
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    implementation("io.micronaut.serde:micronaut-serde-jackson"){
        exclude group: "com.fasterxml.jackson.core", module: "jackson-core"
        exclude group: "com.fasterxml.jackson.core", module: "jackson-databind"
        exclude group: "com.fasterxml.jackson.core", module: "jackson-annotations"

    }
    implementation("io.micronaut.validation:micronaut-validation")
    implementation("jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api")
    implementation("software.amazon.awssdk:dynamodb"){
        exclude group: "software.amazon.awssdk", module: "third-party-jackson-core"
    }
    implementation("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cognitoidp:1.11.759"){
        exclude group: "com.fasterxml.jackson.core", module: "jackson-databind"
    }
    implementation("io.micronaut.aws:micronaut-aws-lambda-events-serde")
    implementation("io.micronaut.aws:micronaut-aws-apigateway")
    implementation("io.micronaut.crac:micronaut-crac")
    implementation("io.micronaut.aws:micronaut-function-aws-api-proxy")

//    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    testImplementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28")
    implementation("com.github.ksuid:ksuid:1.1.1")
    compileOnly("org.graalvm.nativeimage:svm")
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    runtimeOnly("org.yaml:snakeyaml")
    implementation ("com.sendgrid:sendgrid-java:4.7.2"){
        exclude group: "com.fasterxml.jackson.core", module: "jackson-core"
        exclude group: "com.fasterxml.jackson.core", module: "jackson-databind"
        exclude group: "com.fasterxml.jackson.core", module: "jackson-annotations"
    }
    implementation 'com.auth0:java-jwt:3.18.2'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.17.1'

}


application {
    mainClass.set("com.crossbo.userservice.Application")
}
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("17")
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("17")
}

graalvmNative.toolchainDetection = false
micronaut {
//    runtime("netty")
    runtime("lambda_provided")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.crossbo.userservice.*")
    }
    aot {
        // Please review carefully the optimizations enabled below
        // Check https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-aot/latest/guide/ for more details
        optimizeServiceLoading = false
        convertYamlToJava = false
        precomputeOperations = true
        cacheEnvironment = true
        optimizeClassLoading = true
        deduceEnvironment = true
        optimizeNetty = true
    }
}
tasks.named("dockerfileNative") {
    baseImage = "amazoncorretto:11.0.15"
    jdkVersion = "17"
    args(
            "-XX:MaximumHeapSizePercent=80",
            "-Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0",
            "-Dio.netty.noPreferDirect=true"

    )
}


